# Workflow gives error: e-mail address 'someone@example.com' is unknown

Tags: workflow, email

The title of this question comes from the logs of SharePoint 2010. I defined a three-state workflow and the workflow gives errors when trying to send e-mail to the users participating in the workflow. I can't see anywhere 'someone@example.com' is defined. The only configuration was Search Service app configuration and I changed the mail address to a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my scenario the error was caused because my sharepoint server was not authorized to send mails in my mail server.

Comment: Do you have any more information about the steps you took to fix this?

Comment: I'm using a relay mail server on a linux machine. It has an ACL per machine, so if the machine is not authorized the connection is rejected. In my scenario I just needed to add the sharepoint server to the mail relay ACL.
I wrote it here because I thought it was interesting the few information received from the error message. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Might this address be set in your outgoing email settings in Central Admin?

Comment: No changed it to sharepoint@domain.local. I only get this error when SharePoint tries to send an e-mail to the admin user. Suspect that something is wrong with User Profile Sync.

Comment: You can always edit the user's profile, you do not have to rely on synchronization to get details into the profile.

Comment: I edit the profile but it doesn't get synchronized with the normal sites unless I run the synchronization job. The weird thing is, I can see that the mail address is set to sharepoint@domain.local but after synchronization it is set back to someone@example.com. How can I get rid of this someone thing?

Comment: Ok, can please someone explain this thing to me? Central Administration Manage User Profile plage shows the mail address as sharepoint@domain.local. My Profile page at the default web application shows the e-mail field "empty". My Settings page shows the mail address as "someone@example.com". This thing will make me go mad!

Comment: You're suffering from User Profile Hell, a common problem in SharePoint 2010. First things first, i'd recommend checking your email address in Active Directory to check to make sure that field is set properly - if it's reverting itself to the wrong thing, it must be getting that information from somewhere. After you have done that, provided this isn't a production environment, i'd recommend rebuilding your user profile store and user profile sync service. Also, if you haven't yet upgraded to Service Pack 1, i'd recommend giving that a shot.